# Difference between AspnetRoles and aspnet_Roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am getting started with authentication in ASP.net MVC5 and trying to understand authentication. I noticed when running "aspnet_regsql" it generates the tables/sp that begin with "aspnet_" and it also creates a set of tables that start with "AspNet" that have similar functionality (i.e. users, roles, etc).

Does MVC5 utilize the database elements that start with "aspnet_" or only those that start with "AspNet"? If only the latter, is it ok to delete the former?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest default MVC5 template utilizes Identity 2.0 for user/account management, which generates the tables that start with "AspNet". The "aspnet_" tables are generated by the aspnet_regsql tool.

On a side note, you should really stick with Identity, and stay away from the old Membership. It's very outdated, and you get a lot more flexibilty with Identity.